# Union with Concatenated Values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, overlapping-features, union

I have a polygon feature class in which the polygons frequently overlap each other. I want to find all of the unique combinations of overlapping polygons within that feature class. I believe I want to perform a Union on the feature class, but I also want to be able to concatenate the names so that each polygon has a unique name made up of the concatenated name of all the polygons that make it up. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Do the union and then do a spatial join back to the original feature class and in the field map of the Spatial Join tool make the merge rule "Join" for whichever attribute you want to concatenate.

Comment: You're probably going to want to look at python for this. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000
You might find this easier if you create individual feature classes for each unique polygon.

Comment: Are you interested in the result geometry or only the attributes combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Do the union and then do a spatial join back to the original feature class and in the field map of the Spatial Join tool make the merge rule "Join" for whichever attribute you want to concatenate.